# Any name for an isosceles triangle sides

Tags: notation, euclidean-geometry

Is there an English translation for Finnish words kanta and kylki? Namely, if $ABC$ is an isosceles triangle with $AB=AC$ then $BC$ is kanta in Finnish and $AB$, $BC$ are both kylki.

Comment: It seems the *kylki* are usually just called the *equal sides* (e.g. "Let $AB$ be one of the equal sides in the isosceles triangle $ABC$"). I think I've seen *base* for *kanta*, but that may be misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I know four words in Finnish (I also know kani and pieru) The kanta is called the "base" and the kylki (kylit? there are two of them) are called the "legs".

Comment: It's not too difficult to learn counting up to *sata tuhatta* in Finnish :)

Comment: @Tim Thanks. The plural form is "kyljet".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  I'm only interested in counting if I also know the expression for "beers please".  Apparently in Finnish there are three different ways of saying it and you can only ever guess the right one if you're actually Finnish.  Interestingly this approach means that I can effectively count twice as high in Bavaria as I can in the rest of Germany.

Comment: Well, after some beers I can count in mongolian with a czech accent up to $\,4.5\,$ . The problem usually is nobody understands...

Comment: I would say for example "Kaksi kaljaa kiitos" if I would like to have two beers. You can order beer many ways in Finland. Some synonyms for a beer are "kalja, olut, bisse, huurteinen, olvi, taari, keppana"